# Bootstrap 3 with masonry

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I've a problem with a grid using twitter bootstrap (new version 3.0.1) with a fluid container and the jquery masonry plugin.

In default (1200px width) there should be 3 elements in each row. If i start with 4 col-xs-3 elements everything works just fine (see example in comments). But my problem is when starting with col-xs-6 / col-xs-3 / col-xs-3.

The issue can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/andre1404/97eHr/1/

Does not work:

```
<div class="post col-xs-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>
```

Works fine:

```
<div class="post col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>

        <div class="post col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>
```

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 0):

Trying playing around with the `ColumnWidth` parameter.
Change the script to something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var container = $('#posts');

    container.masonry({
        gutter: 0,
        itemSelector: '.post',
        columnWidth: 3
    }); 
});
```

This seems to have the desired effect.